# Access SignalR from domain services and application layer

Tags: signalr-hub, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-signalr

This is directly related to [calling a SignalR Hub from the Application Service Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472303/is-calling-a-signalr-hub-from-the-application-service-layer-a-bad-practice-in-as) in ASP.NET Boilerplate .NET Core version. As per the solution, SignalR hub implementation should be done in Web layer. But the dependency structure of the projects are like:

- App depends on `Domain.Core`
- `Web.Core` depends on App
- `Web.Host` depends on `Web.Core`

Two questions:

1. To be able to use the `Hub` in both `Domain.Core` and App projects, how should I wire it all up? If I define the interface in App layer with a null pattern, I can implement it in `Web.Core`. But then I can't use it in domain services (e.g. `EventBus`).
2. Can I move entire SignalR hub to a new module and reference it from App, Domain and Web layers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. To be able to use the `Hub` in both `Domain.Core` and App projects, how should I wire it all up?

Domain layer:

- `IMyNotifier` interface
- `NullMyNotifier` null implementation

```cs
public interface IMyNotifier
{
    Task SendMessage(IUserIdentifier user, string message);
}

public class NullMyNotifier : IMyNotifier
{
    public static NullMyNotifier Instance { get; } = new NullMyNotifier();

    private NullMyNotifier()
    {
    }

    public Task SendMessage(IUserIdentifier user, string message)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Web layer:

- SignalR hub implementation, e.g. [`MyChatHub`](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/SignalR-AspNetCore-Integration#your-signalr-code)
- `SignalRMyNotifier` concrete implementation

```cs
public class SignalRMyNotifier : IMyNotifier, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IOnlineClientManager _onlineClientManager;
    private readonly IHubContext<MyChatHub> _hubContext;

    public SignalRMyNotifier(
        IOnlineClientManager onlineClientManager,
        IHubContext<MyChatHub> hubContext)
    {
        _onlineClientManager = onlineClientManager;
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(IUserIdentifier user, string message)
    {
        var onlineClients = _onlineClientManager.GetAllByUserId(user);
        foreach (var onlineClient in onlineClients)
        {
            var signalRClient = _hubContext.Clients.Client(onlineClient.ConnectionId);
            await signalRClient.SendAsync("getMessage", message);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage, in any layer that references Domain layer:

```cs
public class MyDomainService : DomainService, IMyManager
{
    public IMyNotifier MyNotifier { get; set; }

    public MyDomainService()
    {
        MyNotifier = NullMyNotifier.Instance;
    }

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        // Do something
        // ...

        var hostAdmin = new UserIdentifier(null, 1);
        var message = "Something done";
        await MyNotifier.SendMessage(hostAdmin, message);
    }
}
```

> 2. Can I move entire SignalR hub to a new module and reference it from App, Domain and Web layers?

You can, but the new module that contains the SignalR hub (and thus your App and Domain layers) would depend on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR`, which depends on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections`. Domain layer should not depend on `Http`.